# Newline stays in buffer after fgets()?

Tags: c, newline, fgets, getchar

Here is the snippet of code that is causing me problems:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 64

char choice;
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
printf("Name: ");
fgets(name, MAX_NAME_LEN, stdin);
choice = getchar();
```

After I enter a name and press enter, getchar() captures the newline as well instead of waiting for the next character. How can I fix my code (without something hacky like another getchar() if possible) so that getchar() will wait for a character as expected after a name is entered?

Comment: You shouldn't add one to `MAX_NAME_LEN` - `fgets()` will only read `n - 1` characters leaving one left over for the terminating NUL.

Comment: Ah, that's right. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate your problem using GCC on a Mac OS X system.  Are you perhaps using a Windows system where pressing `ENTER` might produce both a `CR` and an `LF`?

In any event, note that `getchar()` will not usually return immediately after a single key press because by default on most systems `stdin` is *line buffered*, meaning that the terminal subsystem won't deliver any characters to the user process until `ENTER` is pressed.

`getchar()` is not a substitute for the old DOS `<conio.h>` functions like `getch()`.

Getting around that depends on what O/S you're on.

Comment: fgets always [reads in a newline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) if it sees one. `If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.`

Comment: yup, I didn't say otherwise.  What's unclear is why apparently pressing enter just once causes both his `fgets()` and `getchar()` calls to complete.  It just works, for me.